# Macro that wrap set-face-attribute don't work

Tags: emacs, macros, elisp

I want to create macro that will transform this:

```el
(set-face-attribute 'term-color-blue nil :foreground "#5555FF")
```

into

```el
(term-color blue "#5555FF")
```

I've try this:

```el
(defmacro term-color (name color)
  `(set-face-attribute ',(intern (concat "term-color-" (symbol-name name)))
                       :foreground ,color))
```

but got error `wrong-type-argument symbolp "#5555FF"`, what's wrong with my macro?

Macroexpand return:

```el
(set-face-attribute (quote term-color-blue) :foreground "#5555FF")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nil` is conspicuously missing from the macroexpansion.

Try

```
(defmacro term-color (name color)
  `(set-face-attribute ',(intern (concat "term-color-" (symbol-name name)))
                       nil :foreground ,color))
```

Comment: Beat me by 15 seconds!  @jcubic, please accept this one.